# Navigation Bar not spanning width of page

Tags: css, header, navigationbar

It is my first time putting together a website and I was hoping some of you might be able to help me as there seems to be a wealth of knowledge here. I am having the hardest time trying to have the navigation bar stretch across the length of the webpage. Additionally, there is a space between the photo header and the navigation bar which I'd like to get rid of. I have made it white for now, but when i hover, you can see the white space.

I included all the code (I'm sorry if it's overwhelming, but I'm not sure what's important and what's not as I am adapting it from the current code of a user who is no longer with my lab) and I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thank you so much!

UPDATE: I have made a js fiddle as chandan suggested
http://jsfiddle.net/amchen/rzdmytqz/

I was hoping to make a website similar to the one as the tutorial I looked at:
https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/learn/tutorials/how-to/first-website-part1.html

[image: This is the design I see when I have it in a test webpage]
The picture above is what I am seeing when I do a test webpage.

I hope this gives you a better idea of what I am looking for in terms of design.

THANK YOU!

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 1400px;
min height: 100%;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content-spacer-top {
 height: 150px;
}

#content-spacer-bottom{
height:30px;
}

#header {
background-color: #357f7f;
height: 2%;
width: 100%;
}
#mainnav a {
display: block;
width: 12%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #357F7F;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 0px;
border-top-color: #F0F0F0;
border-right-color: #F0F0F0;
border-bottom-color: #F0F0F0;
border-left-color: #F0F0F0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
word-spacing: normal;
}

#mainnav a:hover,#mainnav a:active,#mainnav a:focus {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #357F7F;
}

a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #357F7F;
}

#footer {
width:100%;
height:6%;
background color:#357f7f
position:absolute;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
}
.style6 {font-size: 12px}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" text="#000000" leftmargin="10%" topmargin="0" rightmargin="10%"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/indexfigures/surfover.jpg','images/indexfigures/3over.jpg' ,'images/indexfigures/4over.jpg','images/indexfigures/5over.jpg')" font>

 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>

 <nav id="mainnav">
  <img src="images/NewTitle copy.jpg" align="middle">
<ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="index.htm">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="research.htm">RESEARCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="susantaylor.htm">SUSAN TAYLOR</a></li>
      <li><a href="LabMembersRecent.htm">LAB MEMBERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="publications.htm">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.htm">LINKS</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="reagents.htm">REAGENT REQUESTS</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>

<div id= "content" align="center"> 
<br>
<div id="content-spacer-top"> </div>
<div id="content-inner"> 

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->

        <table width="75%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
            <td width="20%" height="113" align="center"><a   href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/PKAfigure.htm')" 
                    onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                     onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image14','','images/indexfigures/1over.jpg',1)"><img  src="images/indexfigures/1out.jpg" name="Image14" width="113" height="113" border="0"></a> </td>
            <td width="16%" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/surface.htm')" 
                    onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                     onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image15','','images/indexfigures/surfover.jpg',1)">
                    <img src="images/indexfigures/surfout.jpg" name="Image15"  width="91" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
            <td width="21%" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/Rsub1.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image22','','images/indexfigures/3over.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/3out.jpg" name="Image22" width="161" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
            <td width="12%" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/PBC.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image23','','images/indexfigures/4over.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/4out.jpg" name="Image23" width="95" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
            <td width="19%" align="center">
            <a href="javascript:openWindow('figurepanes/local1.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image24','','images/indexfigures/5over.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/5out.jpg" name="Image24" width="139" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
          </tr>
   </table>

 <table width="75%" align="center" table id="table_text">
  <tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
<div id="content-space bottom"></div>

</div>

<div class="footer" id="footer">
 <div align="center">
<p>content here</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width in #wrapper to 100%. Also, I don't know if it matters but your whole style section looks like it's commented out. Kinda hard to see what is going on since none of your images are visible.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have your navigation inside the main wrapper and '#wrapper' width is 1400px. Take the Navigation out of the main wrapper and it will stretch 100%;

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
 #content {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 1400px;
min height: 100%;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content-spacer-top {
 height: 150px;
}

#content-spacer-bottom{
height:30px;
}

#header {
background-color: #357f7f;
height: 2%;
width: 100%;
}
#mainnav a {
display: block;
width: 12%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #357F7F;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 0px;
border-top-color: #F0F0F0;
border-right-color: #F0F0F0;
border-bottom-color: #F0F0F0;
border-left-color: #F0F0F0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
word-spacing: normal;
}

#mainnav a:hover,#mainnav a:active,#mainnav a:focus {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #357F7F;
}

a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #357F7F;
}

#footer {
width:100%;
height:6%;
background color:#357f7f
position:absolute;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
}
.style6 {font-size: 12px}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" text="#000000" leftmargin="10%" topmargin="0" rightmargin="10%"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/indexfigures/surfover.jpg','images/indexfigures/3over.jpg' ,'images/indexfigures/4over.jpg','images/indexfigures/5over.jpg')" font>


 <div id="header"></div>

 <nav id="mainnav">
  <img src="images/NewTitle copy.jpg" align="middle">
<ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="index.htm">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="research.htm">RESEARCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="susantaylor.htm">SUSAN TAYLOR</a></li>
      <li><a href="LabMembersRecent.htm">LAB MEMBERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="publications.htm">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.htm">LINKS</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="reagents.htm">REAGENT REQUESTS</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
 <div id="wrapper">


<div id= "content" align="center"> 
<br>
<div id="content-spacer-top"> </div>
<div id="content-inner"> 

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->

        <table width="75%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
            <td width="20%" height="113" align="center"><a   href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/PKAfigure.htm')" 
                    onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                     onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image14','','images/indexfigures/1over.jpg',1)"><img  src="images/indexfigures/1out.jpg" name="Image14" width="113" height="113" border="0"></a> </td>
            <td width="16%" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/surface.htm')" 
                    onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                     onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image15','','images/indexfigures/surfover.jpg',1)">
                    <img src="images/indexfigures/surfout.jpg" name="Image15"  width="91" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
            <td width="21%" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/Rsub1.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image22','','images/indexfigures/3over.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/3out.jpg" name="Image22" width="161" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
            <td width="12%" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/PBC.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image23','','images/indexfigures/4over.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/4out.jpg" name="Image23" width="95" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
            <td width="19%" align="center">
            <a href="javascript:openWindow('figurepanes/local1.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image24','','images/indexfigures/5over.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/5out.jpg" name="Image24" width="139" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
          </tr>
   </table>

 <table width="75%" align="center" table id="table_text">
  <tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
<div id="content-space bottom"></div>

</div>

<div class="footer" id="footer">
 <div align="center">
<p>content here</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: chandan, thank you! I have created a fiddle, will you take a look at it? I have also included a link for the design for the website I am trying to model it after. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: Hi chandan, I have finally figured it out! I needed to call#main nav ul and change the parameters. I'm working on figuring out other things (the footer and a drop down menu) but thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi Angela, Most Welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors in your style code. Make sure you input semicolons after every style you want to implement. Also background-color should have the hyphen in between (see the #footer section in your style tag). You wont be able to expand the navbar to 100% of the screen AND have the image in the same plane unless you put both items in a . I have tried as much as I can for now. You can decrease the width of the #mainnav as you increase the size of the image. Also you need to increase the height of the header. 2% height for the header hides most of the content. I used `display:inline-block` to get the navbar and the image in the same plane:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 1400px;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content-spacer-top {
height: 150px;
}

#content-spacer-bottom{
height:30px; 
}

#header {
background-color: #357f7f;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}

#mainnav{
height:50px;
display:inline-block;
width:1300px;
}

#mainnav img{
display:inline-block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
}
#mainnav a {
display: inline-block;
width: 12%;
float:right;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #357F7F;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 0px;
border-top-color: #F0F0F0;
border-right-color: #F0F0F0; 
border-bottom-color: #F0F0F0;
border-left-color: #F0F0F0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
word-spacing: normal;
}

#mainnav a:hover,#mainnav a:active,#mainnav a:focus {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #357F7F;
}

a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #357F7F; 
}

#footer {
width:100%;
height:6%;
background:#357f7f;
position:absolute;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
}
.style6 {font-size: 12px}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" text="#000000" leftmargin="10%" topmargin="0" rightmargin="10%"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/indexfigures/surfover.jpg','images/indexfigures/3over.jpg' ,'images/indexfigures/4over.jpg','images/indexfigures/5over.jpg');">


<div id="header">
<img src="images/NewTitle copy.jpg" align="middle">
<nav id="mainnav">

<ul style="list-style: none;">
  <li><a href="index.htm">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="research.htm">RESEARCH</a></li>
  <li><a href="susantaylor.htm">SUSAN TAYLOR</a></li>
  <li><a href="LabMembersRecent.htm">LAB MEMBERS</a></li>
  <li><a href="publications.htm">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
  <li><a href="links.htm">LINKS</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="reagents.htm">REAGENT REQUESTS</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id= "content" align="center"> 
 <br>
 <div id="content-spacer-top"> </div>
 <div id="content-inner"> 

 <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->

<table width="75%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
<td width="20%" height="113" align="center"><a     href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/PKAfigure.htm')"                 onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"                   onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image14','','images/indexfigures/1over.jpg',1)"><img  src="images/indexfigures/1out.jpg" name="Image14" width="113" height="113" border="0"></a>          </td>
        <td width="16%" align="center">
            <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/surface.htm')" 
                onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
                 onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image15','','images/indexfigures/surfover.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/indexfigures/surfout.jpg" name="Image15"  width="91" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
        <td width="21%" align="center">
            <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/Rsub1.htm')" 
            onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
            onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image22','','images/indexfigures/3over.jpg',1)">
            <img src="images/indexfigures/3out.jpg" name="Image22" width="161" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
        <td width="12%" align="center">
            <a href="javascript:openWindow('Figurepanes/PBC.htm')" 
            onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
            onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image23','','images/indexfigures/4over.jpg',1)">
            <img src="images/indexfigures/4out.jpg" name="Image23" width="95" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
        <td width="19%" align="center">
        <a href="javascript:openWindow('figurepanes/local1.htm')" 
            onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
            onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image24','','images/indexfigures/5over.jpg',1)">
            <img src="images/indexfigures/5out.jpg" name="Image24" width="139" height="113" border="0"></a>                </td>
      </tr>
 </table>

 <table width="75%" align="center" table id="table_text">
 <tr>
 <th scope="col"></th>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
 <div id="content-space bottom"></div>

 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="footer" id="footer">
 <div align="center">
 <p>content here</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for making all these corrections for me! I actually entered this into adobe dreamweaver and got a strange looking webpage. Will you take a look at my jsfiddle and the link for the type of page I am trying to design? I really appreciate your input!